# What is an Architecture Context Diagram (ACD) and are there any other names for it?

Tags: architecture, uml, diagram, software-design

I've been charged with the following tasks for a group project:

a) Design/Draw an Architecture Context Diagram
b) ACD Description
c) UML deployment diagram

The UML deployment diagram is no issue as there are plenty of straight-forward resources online but this is not the case for the ACD.

**I need resources on exactly what an ACD is and how to draw one.**

Is there another name for an ACD such as Architecture Context Diagram such as Architecture Interconnection Diagram or Operations Systems Diagram? I keep coming across similar names but different diagrams in Google searches...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The teacher eventually showed us a diagram she drew up. I figure this diagram doesn't exist except in her class!

Comment: I realize this is from 2010, but is it possible you could post the diagram you got?

Answer (score 2):

I figured you've tried Wikipedia however, I found this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_context_diagram

I have a feeling that a System Context Diagram is the same thing (or quite similar) to an Architecture context Diagram.

Is the diagram in question a UML based diagram?

---

Since you indicated that it is a UML diagram, I can only suggest that you [check out OMG's site](http://www.omg.org/). You should be able to [get a copy of the UML standards document](http://www.omg.org/technology/documents/modeling_spec_catalog.htm#UML) without signing up. I'm sorry I don't have a more direct answer for you. I've only heard about the System Context Diagram. While I had searched for something like a Architecture Context Diagram, the system one is the closest I came.

Comment: Yes it is an UML diagram (I assume so because that's all we do). That's actually the first page I tried...it might be the same but it's the little differences I might lose marks for that I'm trying to avoid...

Comment: "lose marks" -- forgive me but is this homework?

Comment: No worries, thanks for resource. I'll definitely check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Architectural Context Diagram is a graphic representation of your system and of the external components that interact with the system. This components are linked to the system via interfaces, ilustred by a rectangle above your system, like in this image: tinyurl.com/jabyt3q

There are 4 elements in ACD:

1. Superiors Systems - systems wich uses the main system for realize your functions
2. Subordinated Systems - system wich are used by main system for it realize your functions
3. Peers - systems (components) in the same level of the main system
4. Actors - external entities wich uses the main system produzing and consuming data

Sorry if i don't explain in a didadic way, but my english is not good and i don't want use the Google Tradutor, so, i hope had be clear in my words. :P

For more information i recommend you read Pressman's book of Software Engeneering. In the 8 or 9 chapter he explain this very well. Pressman is the law! :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like two diagrams I've worked with - Architecture Overview and System Context diagram.  This represents the system under development as a circle in the middle of the diagram and then shows external actors either human or system interfaces around the outside.

The idea of the System Context is to quickly develop and communicate who the users of the system under development is and what systems it interfaces with.  The actual internals of the system under development aren't shown.

The Architecture Overview then provides more of a view of key things within the system e.g. layering and key elements of the system

I've read more discussion on this topic here: http://softwarearchitecturezen.blogspot.com/2009/08/two-diagrams-all-architects-need.html